# Selecting cells when criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that I am trying to get it to look through column B to see if it is highlighted and then select that column and its associate column A value. I have written something and it selects the last cell that meets the criteria but not all of them. Anybody know what is happening? I have provided my code below. Thanks in advance

```
ws.Select
For Each rng In ws.Range("C2:C" & lastrow)
If rng.Interior.Color = 65535 Then
ws.Range("B" & rng.Row).resize(1,2).select
End If
Next rng
```

Comment: I think You can use `Union` to select all of them.

Comment: Yes, `union` is what you would use if you want to leverage your existing code

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Dim uRng As Range  
ws.Select
For Each Rng In Ws.Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
 If Rng.Interior.Color = 65535 Then
    If uRng Is Nothing Then
     Set uRng = Ws.Range("B" & Rng.Row)
    Else
     Set uRng = Union(uRng, Ws.Range("B" & Rng.Row))
    End If
 End If
Next Rng

If Not uRng Is Nothing Then uRng.Select
```

When we select a cell then select another cell, the first selection will removed so we need to select all cells in one `Select` action, by using `Union` we can do that

Comment: @BriannaCates, You are Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, but you should test it on a copy, not your original.

dim myRange as Range

```
ws.Select
For Each rng In ws.Range("C2:C" & lastrow)
If rng.Interior.Color = 65535 Then
set myrange = myrange union (ws.Range("B" & rng.Row))
End If
Next rng

myRange .resize(1,2).select
```